# Ajax Call loading gps getting [object%20HTMLInputElement] 404 Not Found Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

I'm making an Ajax call to a Grails controller that renders a  GSP template to an html element. The 404 error popup on the Google Dev. Console but besides that the GSP template seems to load fine, and everything else functions like it should. Why am I getting this error?

There just seems to be a problem loading the GSP page. I'm not sure why that is causing that problem. The GSP page loads without any noticeable errors, and functionally it seems to be working fine.

```
function showLinkSummary() {
    jQuery("input[name='summary']").prop("disabled", true);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "${url}",
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
            jQuery("input[name='summary']").prop("disabled", false);
            jQuery("#summaryOfLinks").html(data);
            jQuery("#summaryOfLinks").removeClass("hiddenPopup");
            jQuery("#summaryOfLinks").addClass("shownPopup");
            jQuery("#grayOut").removeClass("hiddenPopup");
            jQuery("#grayOut").addClass("shownPopup");
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            jQuery("#summaryOfLinks").html('Error:'  + errorThrown + ' with Status: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

This is the error I'm getting on the dev console:
http://www.medhome.local:8081/admin/linkChecker/[object%20HTMLInputElement] 404 (Not Found)

Comment: on success call back function log data to console like - console.log(data) and see which property gives html code in data object '

Comment: the data object should be returning an html page (gsp), is that a problem?

Comment: yes, clearly data is not returning HTML, see if data.somproperty is returning HTML code